# run-time exception on const array variables

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, constants

I am wondering what is happening in the situation below:

I have the following function:

```
void some_func(const int * a, int len_of_a) {
    int * b = (int *) a;
    b[1] = 3;
}
```

a is a pointer to constant ints, so supposedly I cannot change anything inside array a. But I tried to tweak the pointer and change the elements inside. The code compiles, and when it runs and when I pass in some constant array, I get a run time exception.

I'm wondering what is actually causing this exception. Is that memory region marked as readable only by the OS? or is there some hardware support that causes this exception? What's behind the scene?

Comment: Yes, `const` doesn't guarantee that you cant change the data, it just prevents accidentally changing it, but you can always cast the `const` away. But you need to post how you define `a`.

Comment: the memory region is likely marked as RO. show the calling code and the definition of the passed "a". is this a debug build?

Comment: You're trying to change the value in `b[1]` which probably points to the stack, if you were trying to change the original `a` you should set `b[0]` or `*b`

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it depends on what `a` actually points to. If it points to non-const data then it's OK to modify it by casting away the const. If it points to something that was declared `const` then it's [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

I don't know if the same is true for [c](/questions/tagged/c).

```
const int a1[] = { 1, 2, 3 }
some_func(a1, 3); // undefined behaviour

int a2[] = { 1, 2, 3 }
some_func(a2, 3); // OK
```

This means that you should only cast away constness if you know for sure everything about the object you're handling. Which is obviously not true for general functions that accept `const` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As per general rules, if you try to access a `const` variable through a pointer of non-`const` type, produces [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

So, your program behavior will rely on what type of argument has been passed to your `some_func()`. If it is an address of a `const` variable, then surely your program will face UB. To be on safer side, *if you know what you're doing*, avoid `const` or avoid modifying the `const`.

In your particular case,

> *when I pass in some constant array, I get a run time exception.*

You're facing UB, as the array is `const` and you're not supposed to change the contents of that array.

That said, you need to be sure about accessing the correct memory. Inside your function, there is no way for compiler to know whether `b[1]` is a valid access or not. You need to make sure the access is valid, i.e., the pointer is allocated enough memory so that `b[1]` is a valid element access through that pointer.

Related, as per `C11` standard, chapter 6.7.3,

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: So it depends on how the object pointed to by `a` was defined and is not always UB?

Comment: I guess I'm more interested in how the exception is generated, like behind the scene. I mean, I understand that one should never do something like that in their program. What exactly is happening behind the scene? like let's say this is written in C and running on Linux. Is the operating system keeping track of all the constants structures and throw the exceptions? I mean, yes, this can generate undefined behavior. But what's actually happening in the system level?